# Calculate entropy of a sphere (?)

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy

I saw these two videos ([1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTeJ64KD5cg?t=35) and [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GCf29FPM4k?t=454)) and in both of them Tony Padilla gives basically the same definition of maximum entropy in a region of space (a sphere). Now, searching the web I haven't found any practical definition of maximum entropy, nevertheless a "maximum entropy of a sphere" or simply "entropy of a sphere" (I do not know much about thermodynamics, hence I do not know if either of them exist), but I do know that entropy is measured in J/K or $kg\cdot m^{2}\cdot s^{-2}\cdot K^{-1}$.
The formulas he uses, instead, have a dimension of metres $m$.

Is there a correct definition of the entropy that he wants to use?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. What he means by "maximum entropy of a sphere" is the entropy of a black hole the size of that sphere.
He states that the maximum entropy of a black hole is $$S=\frac{A}{4{ℓ_{p}}^{2}}$$ but i suppose that is written in dimensionless form or reduced form. So the actual entropy should be: $$S=\frac{k_{B}A}{4{ℓ_{p}}^{2}}$$ which for the average size of the human brain (volume of $1260\,cm^3$, so an average radius of $0.067\,\text{m}$) evaluates at $\approx 7.456×10^{44} J/K$, which is clearly less then Graham's number.